# Virtualbox. доступ в интернет через NAT интерфейс другой машины

Tags: linux, сеть, virtualbox, nat, виртуальная-машина

Есть две виртуальные машины, VM1 и VM2 на базе centos. На первой стоит NAT интерфейс. Что нужно сделать, что бы VM2 могла ходить в интернет через NAT первой машины?

Comment: Создать на каждой по сетевому адаптеру и объединить их во "внутреннюю сеть".